# Can't access value stored in $_SESSION array in php

Tags: php, session

I am attempting to set a value into the $_SESSION super global in the page set.php
this the snippet :

```
if (isset($_POST['sales']) && $_POST['sales'] != ""){
    $sales = sanitize_input(trim($_POST['sales']));
    $_SESSION['nam0'] = $sales;
    $host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
    $extra = 'access.php';
    header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra?so=".$sales);
    exit();
 }
```

and to access the value stored in `$_SESSION['nam0']` in access.php like this:

```
<?php
/*To check availbality of SOs for given Sales Order Number in so.php*/
// Initialize session
   session_start();
   $SD_ID = $_SESSION['nam0'];
```

However, I am hitting the following error:
Notice: Undefined index: nam0 in access.php on line 7

I don't know why. Can someone help me on this?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Presumably you have a `session_start()` in `set.php`?

Comment: in set.php have you start session? have you try use session name without number?

Answer (score 0):

Session are used like this:

```
<?php

session_start();

echo $_SESSION['key'] ?? 'key not found';
```

You can always dump the contents of the session array by doing `var_dump($_SESSION);`.

I'm guessing that you havn't set your index (submitted the form) yet and therefore getting a "Undefined Index".